# Verificar se valor da variavel já existe em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Boa noite!
Estou tentando verificar se o valor atribuído a uma variável já esta presente em uma lista mas não está funcionando. Já pesquisei sobre comparar valores em listas mas não consegui de nenhuma forma. Desde já, agradeço.

A ideia é:
Selecionar todos os cnpj (pk) - OK; Coloca-los em uma lista (cnpjck)-OK; Verificar se existe o cnpj digitado na lista - Fail

```
cnpjck=[]
c.execute("SELECT cnpj FROM clientes") #Selecionar todos os cnpj
check_cnpj = c.fetchall()

for i in check_cnpj: #lista de cnpj
    cnpjck.append(i)
print(cnpjck)

for i in range (len(cnpjck)):
    print ("entrei no segundo for") # Funciona até aqui;
    if cnpj in cnpjck: # Acredito que o erro esteja aqui, já tentei: if cnpj in cnpjck[1], também ja tentei inserir o valor manual ex: if '12345' in cnpjck[i]
        print("cnpj já cadastrado")
```

Como insiro os dados no banco:

```
        c.execute("INSERT INTO clientes VAlUES(:i_cnpj, :i_name, :i_email, :i_date)",
        {
        'i_cnpj': input_cnpj.get(),
        'i_name': input_name.get(),
        'i_email': input_email.get(),
        'i_date': input_data_inc.get()
        }
    )
```

Saída do print da lista:
[(12345678000123,), (12345678000321,)]

Obrigado!

Comment: Se comparares uma string com um número ela não vai ser encontrada.

Comment: Obrigado! Faltou converter. Deu certo!